как написать сообщение в event on_voice_state
мне надо сделать так чтобы при повышении рейтинга написать сообщение, но в on_voice_state нет ctx или что-то типо того
'''
    @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
            if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
                self.t1 = time.time()
            elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
                t2 = time.time()
                self.data_time[member.mention] += t2 - self.t1
                if self.data_time[member.mention] >= 86400:
                    self.data_time[member.mention] -= 86400
                    self.rating[member.mention] += 2
'''

